# Cognos Analytics (Cognos 11)

Tags: upgrade, cognos, cognos-10, cognos-bi

Im trying to find some information about the Cognos analytics but without success.
Im trying to find out what is the latest version of Cognos 11 that is availible and When it was the version released?
How much updates this release have already?
How much bugs were discovered?
Does the upgrade from Cognos 10 to 11 is smooth?

Thanks alot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the question appears a bit broad, I will try to answer the parts of the question I can understand and, hopefully, it will assist the OP.

These are the approximate release dates for the Cognos Analytics 11 that have been released as of the time of this post:

- 11.0.0: December 23, 2015
- 11.0.1: March 29, 2016
- 11.0.2: May 6, 2016

Interestingly, while the 11.0.1 and 11.0.2 releases are seeming to include fixes only, IBM does not appear to be using Fix Packs in the same way as prior releases of Cognos BI.  These are full releases that install and upgrade in the same way as if you were upgrading from BI 10.2.1 to 10.2.2 .  There have been at least two interim fixes (IF) released as well, one for 11.0.0 and one for 11.0.2, both related to security, if I recall correctly.

While I don't think there is any official statistic on how many bugs were discovered, fix lists can be found for the released versions here:

- [11.0.0](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27047208)
- [11.0.1](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27047828)
- [11.0.2](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27048098)

The upgrade process from Cognos 10 to 11 is smooth in the sense that the overall process is similar to upgrades in past releases.  There are some architectural changes for multi-node environments that change the process for installing subsequent nodes.  That said, there are some very important deprecations and feature changes/removals that you will want to learn about, not to mention the new navigation, authoring, and content consumption interfaces.

There are a lot of facets to the release that need considering for any production upgrade -- I would definitely jump into the [documentation](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27047187#cbiv11r0m0en) and, assuming you are a current customer, set up a sandbox to start testing functionality before I made any hard plans for moving a production system forward.  If you want more very high level feature discussion, a quick Google search for "Cognos 11 new features" or similar will give you a lot of helpful information.

Comment: Thanks alot, your answer was  very helpfull

Answer (score 0):

To follow the announcements on the latest releases, you can subscribe to the IBM Analytics blog:
https://www.ibm.com/communities/analytics/cognos-analytics/blog/
or periodically check the product page:
https://www.ibm.com/analytics/us/en/technology/products/cognos-analytics/

For bug fixes, you should refer to the product release notes:
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27047187
, though the list of bugs seem to be less granular than what you would normally see from other IBM products. The list of bugs does not seem to be broken down by fix pack either.

I do not think the upgrade is a smooth one, since it is not an in-place upgrade like you would have from, let's say, 11.0.1 to 11.0.6. I also could not find a clear statement about the upgrade from 10.x in the installation guide, so it is unclear (for me, as of now) whether the process entails the usual backup of the content manager database from original version and restore the backup image to a new database to be used by the new version

I tried exporting the contents from the 10.x installation via Cognos Admin console and then importing it into the 11.0x release, but 3 out of 5 of my reports simply hang on launch even after performing a report upgrade operation via Admin console.